Returning anonymous functions from IIFE
Suppose we have
type GenFunc = <A = void, B = void>({ a?: A, b?: B }) => Promise<void>

I have written a IIFE to return a function that does something depending on an external variable
const num = 1;
const genFunc: GenFunc = (() => {
    switch (num) {
    case 1: 
        return async({ a, b }) => {
            console.log(a)
            console.log(b)
            await fetch("https://example.com") // generic awaited function
        }
    case 2:
      ...
      ...
      ...
    default:
        return async () => {}
    }
})()


I'm not able to access the a and b defined in GenFunc definition inside the function definition under the switch
Is this the best way to return various definitions of a function (with the same signature) such that it can be used on a case by case basis.

I've been scratching my head for a while now, can't seem to go around it
I have tried in general going through the docs on more of generics and anonymous function, plus how the arrow functions are typed.
Still I seem to miss where the generics are to be placed in the IIFE where the function can be assigned to the genFunc definition
EDIT 1: Minimum Reproducible example
Just wanted to know if there is a better way to dynamically change the behaviour of a function at runtime

This code is syntactically invalid (you have function and => together for some reason, for example). Please look at it in an IDE and then [edit] to make this a [mre] where the only issues present are the ones you're asking about.

"I'm not able to access the a and b defined in GenFunc definition inside the function definition under the switch" ─ what do you mean? You only wrote a function with the parameter for an object with the a and b properties under case 1:, but in that function you use the variable a. Your default: returns a function with the wrong signature, taking {body, params} instead of {a, b}. And ... ... ... is not valid Typescript; I know you didn't intend for it to be, but you need to include a [mcve], meaning your exact code should produce the specific issue you are asking about.

• Please [edit] your [mre] into the question as plaintext. The code in the question is still in error, and while the playground link is a nice supplement, it doesn't suffice by itself. I'd do the edit but it's not clear that anyone but you has the rights to copy your code from an external site into here. • What do you mean by "I'm not able to access the a and b defined in GenFunc definition..."? Please [edit] to show this with the code so it jumps out at us. • You have 2 questions; pls remove one of them so the post is focused. I recommend removing the second one, as it's subjective.
